# How to get jinja2 variables from included files

Tags: jinja2

I am writing a program that should include rather long text chunks in an html-file generated through jinja2. Because of a complex macro structure, I want to structure these texts as jinja2 variables, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
{% set standard_text = "This is the standard text." %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    {{standard_text}}
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine, but since these texts can be rather long, I want to have them in separate files. So I created a file called text.html:

```
{% set standard_text = "This is the standard text." %}
```

and put it into a library called templates/standard_texts. Now I want to import it into the html file and I have tried the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
{% include 'templates/standard_texts/text.html' %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    {{standard_text}}
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I run this, I get this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'standard_text' is undefined
```

I have also tried other methods, such as

```
{% from 'templates/standard_texts/text.html import standard_text %}
```

or

```
{% extends'templates/standard_texts/text.html' %}
```

but that does not work either. I have read through Jinja2's "Template Designer Documentation" (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#), but I wasn't able to find anything there either.

How is this done?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I made very silly error when testing option number two, using from ... import. There was an unmatched single quote, and with that fixed, it works. So corrected, the document looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
{% from 'templates/standard_texts/text.html' import standard_text %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    {{standard_text}}
  </body>
</html>
```